# Latex not working with matplotlib since it can't find kpsewhich

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, latex

Whenever I try to use latex with matplotlib I get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'kpsewhich': 'kpsewhich'
```

A minimal working example is

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc

rc("text", usetex = True)

plt.plot(1,2)

plt.show()
```

I am currently running python 3.6.4 and miktex 2.9.6600. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You need to first check if you can call `kpsewhich` from the command line. If you can't, this is not a matplotlib problem, but a problem with the tex installation. If `kpsewhich` is called correctly from the command line, one would need some more information about *how*  you run the python script.

Comment: Hi! whenever I try to run kpsewhich I get ~bash: kpsewhich: command not found. How can I configure my tex installation properly? I am running MacOS High Sierra version 10.13.6

Comment: It needs to be in your path. Now, I personally have no experience with macs, but googling for something like "add miktex to path macos" which brings up e.g. [this page](https://miktex.org/howto/modify-path) might help.

Comment: Thank you very much! I already tried that but didn't work. I can't seem to find where the path for    kpsewhich    may be.

Comment: It should be in the same folder as your `latex`.

Comment: I think that the problem is that I don't have it. Do you know where I can download it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar issues. One problem is that python does not load all of the $PATHs for some reason, in my case those that are set under etc/paths.d. The TeX path is inside etc/paths.d/TeX and is ignored by Python. I have filed a bug on matplotlib (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18991) but it may be a Python issue

I would suggest the following. First, find where your tex distribution is located by typing `which pdflatex` on your os terminal. In my case it's in `/Library/TeX/texbin`.

Second, check if Python is aware of that path

```
import os
print(os.environ['PATH'])
```

If the path is not there, either add it on your .bash_profile, or do the following in your Python code:

```
import os
os.environ['PATH'] += '/Library/TeX/texbin'
```

(change /Library/TeX/texbin to wherever your tex distribution is located)

If you still get a kpsewhich error, my guess is that the font you want to use is missing in your system.